# How to add bootstrap js in a Gatsby Website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, gatsby

I have been tweaking in Gatsby and by far it provides seamless functionality for static websites. I have stack where I need to design layouts using bootstrap as far as layouts are concerned bootstrap works well but for additional support like dropdowns carousel or modal I have to use bootstrap.js and it's dependencies though in local environment everything works fine but when I am deploying my website our netlify I am facing this issue

```
4:25:02 PM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
4:25:01 PM:   7 | //# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.js.map
4:25:01 PM: 
4:25:01 PM:   WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot set property 'emulateTransitionEnd' of undefin  ed
4:25:01 PM:   
4:25:01 PM:   - bootstrap.min.js:6 
4:25:01 PM:     [lib]/[bootstrap]/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6:2564
4:25:01 PM:   
4:25:01 PM:   - bootstrap.min.js:6 ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
4:25:02 PM: Shutting down logging, 58 messages pending
```

After further digging over this issue in official repo and over google most people are recommending react-bootstrap or reactstrap but I am very much bound to bootstrapjs and unable to find out the  proper fix for the above error is there anyway or best way to include bootstrap js? Here is my package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "gatsby": "^2.8.2",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.1.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.0.12",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^2.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.0.11",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.1.3",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.0.38",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.1.21",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.17.1"
  },
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Might be a silly question, but does `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js` exist in your project?

Comment: @An0nC0d3r obviously yes, check the package json and it's working completely fine in local environment as of now I have used bootstrapjs for dropdown in my navbar which is working fine in local so yes it does exists.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Fixed this by adding my bootstrap dependencies in `gatsby-browser.js` (if it is not present in your project add it in your root directory by creating a fresh file with the same name `gatsby-browser.js`).

First, I **installed the dependencies** using `npm`:

`npm install bootstrap jquery @popperjs/core`

And, here is how I have **added in `gatsby-browser.js`**:

```
import './src/sass/app.scss'
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.min'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

`app.scss` is the file where I have imported my bootstrap components along with my custom styles.

Alternatively, you can use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) which removes the unnecessary `jQuery` dependency for bootstrap but uses bootstrap styling to style its own component.

**UPDATE**

The `popper.js` has been deprecated and now it can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@popperjs/core)

Thanks, Ben for pointing it out,

**UPDATE [May 2021]:**

**Bootstrap released v5 on 5th May 2020, so those who are working with Bootstrap v5 should follow these instructions.**

In Bootstrap v5. Bootstrap is migrating from 1.x.x to 2.xx popper.js and therefore :

Step 1: First change the Bootstrap version: `npm i bootstrap@next`

Step 2: Update Popper.js to v2 `npm i @popperjs/core`

Step 3: In `gatsby-browser.js` add the following imports

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js";
```

Comment: alternatively you can use `<Helmet>` and wrap your third party lib inside it either as a link or script tag

Comment: @Rikin yes I can but I don't want to actually I only want to import those components which I need in designing no unused css.

Comment: I inherited a site that used Bootstrap and needed to be brought into Gatsby without a lot of time and this is the only solution that worked. Note that I was able to at least only import the components that I needed for Bootstrap, so I did `import 'bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js'` Thank you!

Comment: Why can't I find `popper.js` on npm?

Comment: it can be find here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@popperjs/core popper.js has been deprecated.

Comment: i'm still getting can't resolve 'popper.js' in 'path/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'

this is how i imported it in gatsby-browser.js
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
import '@popperjs/core'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'

Any help?

Comment: Resolved my issue by following the updated steps from @kushal below

Comment: How do I use the imports in the gattsby-browser.js file?

Comment: @Mr. Pyramid I followed your instructions to the 'T' but or some reason, the bootstrap js events are not firing. Any idea what the issue might be?

Answer (score 11):

[Almost similar as the accepted answer.]

Another way to add Bootstrap and related dependency with gatsby is adding them in `gatsby-browser.js` like following:

**Step 1:** Run `npm i bootstrap jquery popper.js`

**Step 2:** In `gatsby-browser.js` add following imports

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "popper.js/dist/popper.min";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
```

> *Note:* if `gatsby-browser.js` is already present and contains ES5 code, then that needs to converted to ES6 first

**UPDATE [Jan 2021]:**

After the Bootstrap v5.0.0; these steps have changed because Bootstrap's migration from 1.x.x to 2.xx Popper.js and complete removal of JQuery:

Now the steps are:
**Step 1:** First change the Bootstarp version t0 5:
`npm i bootstrap@^5.0.0`

**Step 2:** Update Popper.js to v2
`npm i @popperjs/core@^2.5.4`

**Step 3:** In `gatsby-browser.js` add the following imports

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js";
```

Comment: To highlight the difference, kushal imports the bootstrap CSS file, where as Mr. Pyramid imports a SASS file. If you don't know about SASS, its probably better to copy this import block instead.

Answer (score 5):

To use `react-bootstrap`

**STEP 1:**

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

**STEP 2:** Load your bootstrap in `gatsby-browser.js`

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

If you don't have a `gatsby-browser.js`, create `gatsby-browser.js` in your root folder and add the above snippet

Also, I had to restart my server for it to reflect in gatsby development server

**ref:** https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: There is no major difference between the answer you posted and the answer which has been accepted.

Comment: there is, 1. this uses react-bootstrap 2. shows what to do when `gatsby-browser.js` is not present (I faced this)

Comment: Yes, because it is not related to the main question if it is not there you can check in their website how to create one.

Comment: it is related. when I searched for this, I landed on this link. saving some time for people who come here like me

Comment: @SahithVibudhi Thanks  I am getting this issue DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for http://localhost:8000/bootstrap.min.css.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 1):

Working in Gatsby 4.4.0 and tried doing this approach. gatsby-browser.js was requiring me to import using the node style which is `require`.

So I got this to work by doing it this way:

```js
require("bootstrap/js/src/carousel")
require("bootstrap/js/src/dropdown")
```

As for the bootstrap scss you can import it into a .scss file manually and have it build into your stylesheet. You will need to `npm install sass gatsby-plugin-sass` to get sass working.

Create your file:
`/src/scss/bootstrap.scss`

Inside the file add whatever needed:

```css
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/carousel";
```

Then just add it into your gatsby-browser.js file as well:

```js
require("./src/scss/bootstrap.scss")
require("bootstrap/js/src/carousel")
require("bootstrap/js/src/dropdown")
```

This is better so you can control which elements you need instead of just everything.

Comment: Popping in here in 2024... with the (relatively) new radix UI, I can also confirm that in `gatsby-browser.js`, `require('@radix-ui/themes/styles.css');` worked while `import '@radix-ui/themes/styles.css';` did NOT... very strange